# create react app cannot read environment variable after build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I have a react app , created with `create-react-app` then I build the app with command: `npm run build`

It's using `serve` to run the app after build, if we start the app with development code by running `ENV=production npm run start` it can read the `process.env.ENV` variable beacause I'm adding this plugins to webpack dev config

```
   new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env':{
        'ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.ENV),
      }
    }),
```

I also add the script above to webpack prod config, but if I try this command after build `ENV=prod serve -s build`, it cannot read the environment variable

How to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why you can not read the `ENV` var is because:

(1) In *development* mode `webpack` watches your files and bundles you app on the fly. It also will read (because of the `DefinePlugin`) your `process.env.ENV` and will add it as a global variable. So it is basically piping variables from `process.env` to your JS app.

(2) After you've *build*  your app (with `webpack`) everything is already bundled up into one or more files. When you run `serve` you just start a HTTP server that serves the *static* build files. So there is no way to pipe the `ENV` to you app.

Basically what the `DefinePlugin` does is add a `var` to the bundle. E.g.

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'token': '12356234ga5q3aesd'
})
```

will add a line similar to this:

```
var token = '12356234ga5q3aesd';
```

since the JS files is *static*  there is no way to change this variable *after*  you've build/bundled it with `webpack`. Basically, when you do `npm run build` you're creating the compiled binary/`.dll`/`.jar`/... file and can no longer influence its contents via the plugin.

Comment: so the solution is, i have to add a static flag variabel with `DefinePlugin` that tells if it's production or dev, am i right? or there is any solution?

Comment: Yes, CRA is setup to add everthing under `process.env` to the define plugin. See https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/e12d053c273037c5ec75971ddcd117b3e9858cdf/packages/react-scripts/config/env.js#L89-L95
It will also automatically set prod/dev for you -> `process.env.NODE_ENV`

Comment: @SebastianSebald is right about the bundle taking place at build time. But there is actually a way to replace ENV variables post-build, and this is what we are doing in our company: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61881757/5465000

Answer (score 8):

If you set all the environment variables inside the `app.config.js`, you can  replace them **after the build** in the `main.????????.chunk.js` file.

A sample `app.config.js` could look like:

```js
export default {
  SOME_URL: "https://${ENV_VAR_1}"
  SOME_CONFIGURATION: "${ENV_VAR_2}",
}
```

Leave the `app.config.js` file as is, **without** replacing the environment variables with their actual values. Then, create the optimized production build:

```sh
npm ci # if not already installed
npm run build
```

If the default webpack configurations are used, the contents of `app.config.js` will be bundled in `build/static/js/main.????????.chunk.js`. The values of the environment variables can be be [envsubst](https://www.npmjs.com/package/envsub), with a bash script like this:

```sh
main_chunk=$(ls build/static/js/main.*.js)
envsubst <$main_chunk >./main_chunk_temp
cp ./main_chunk_temp $main_chunk
rm ./main_chunk_temp
```

Note: In the above example, envsubst reads the actual variables set in the environment at runtime and *literally* replaces `${ENV_VAR_1}` and `${ENV_VAR_2}` with them. So, **you can only run this once** as the chunk is being over-written.

Comment: where do I setup the app.config.js file would that be in the root directory and how do I use it after build to change the env variables ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `.env` file to the root of your project and define your environment variables there. That will be your default (production) environment variables definition. But then you can have a local file called `.env.local` to override values from the default.

When defining your environment variables, make sure they start with `REACT_APP_` so your environment variable definitions would look like this:

```
REACT_APP_SERVER_URL=https://my-awesome-app.herokuapp.com
```

Also, add this to .gitignore so you don't commit your local overrides:

```
.env*.local
```

Reference: 
[Adding Development Environment Variables In .env (create-react-app)](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env)

Comment: if i am running a react app that already has the webpack bundled( using create-react-app myapp). Do I need to do anything to include the .env? if I had multiple .env would I have to do anything?

Comment: This solution would not work if the build is already bundled. The .env file and its `REACT_APP` variables are read during build not at serve time!

Answer (score -1):

From [create-react-app documentation](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables):

> Your project can consume variables declared in your environment as if
>   they were declared locally in your JS files. By default you will have
>   NODE_ENV defined for you, and any other environment variables starting
>   with REACT_APP_.

You can read them from process.env inside your code:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <small>You are running this application in <b>{process.env.NODE_ENV}</b> mode.</small>
      <form>
        <input type="hidden" defaultValue={process.env.REACT_APP_NOT_SECRET_CODE} />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```