# Different .env files on different servers?

Tags: reactjs, server, environment, .env

I develop a React (Vite) app that will run on different servers and call different APIs (URLs). Like https://api.serverA.com, https://api.serverB.com.

So as I understand I can use .env files to this.
But what I want to do and think is possible is to create different .env-files and place them manually on the servers. When the React app runs, it then reads the stored .env-file on that server. Is this possible? And how to do it?

When reading about this it usually says that you create different .env-files in your src-folder and then when you BUILD, your .env files is used. But this way I have to do a build for server A and do another build for server B and so on. Instead of doing one build that reads the .env-files stored on the servers.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research I found out the answer seems to be No React can't read an external .env file. When you build your App it is "locked" (static).
Read this post: [create react app cannot read environment variable after build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45561432/create-react-app-cannot-read-environment-variable-after-build)

So my solution is just to check the current url and dynamic create link to api.
Something like this:

```
export const APIURL = () => {
  //first check if we are in developement mode like localhost:3000
  if (import.meta.env.DEV) {
    return 'http://localhost:8888/mylocation/myapi/';
  }

  //do we have a build?
  if (import.meta.env.PROD) {
    //build the api url dynamic to current location
    if (window.location.hostname === 'localhost') {
      const urlParts = window.location.pathname.split('/');
      return window.location.origin + '/' + urlParts[1] + '/myapi/';
    } 
else return window.location.origin + '/myapi/';
  }

  return 'API-URL-IS-MISSING!';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [react-inject-env](https://github.com/codegowhere/react-inject-env)
It will create a `env.js` file from your `.env` file.
Then in your HTML, you load that `env.js` file using a simple script tag and then load your app's bundle (By default it will load last if you're using a bundler).
For this to work, you will need to modify the way you consume your ENV variables a little bit. See the `Update Code` section in their readme

Answer (score 0):

On the servers, it is better to use the ENV systems and not files.

This means that you can do one of the followings:

1. Use the hosts environment settings to set the correct values for each env key needed.
2. You can set a .env file with the correct values, as suggested above.
3. You can create a docker image with the correct env injected.

I usually prefer to use the host environment settings, as it is clear and easier to maintain